# No module named 'allennlp.data.tokenizers.word_splitter'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, allennlp

I'm using python 3.7 in google colab. I install `allennlp=2.4.0` and `allennlp-models`.

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
from allennlp.data.tokenizers.word_splitter import SpacyWordSplitter
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'allennlp.data.tokenizers.word_splitter'

Comment: `SpacyWordSplitter` no longer exists in the latest version of AllenNLP. Where did you read about using `SpacyWordSplitter`? `SpacyWordSplitter` was replaced with `SpacyTokenizer`.

Comment: @arjuns thanks. I replaced SpacyWordSplitter with SpacyTokenizer, but I got that error again.

Comment: Just to confirm - your import statement is `from allennlp.data.tokenizers.spacy_tokenizer import SpacyTokenizer`